# Combine few xml files: encoding problems

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

My application gets from web service few xml files like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<root> 
    <person> 
    <!— some elements here —> 
    </person> 
    <person> 
    <!— some elements here —> 
    </person> 
</root>
```

I combine all this files in one file to join all persons under one root element. If I use code like this:

```
var readers = files.Select(XmlReader.Create).ToList(); 
var writer = XmlWriter.Create("final.xml"); 
... 
writer.WriteStartDocument(); 
writer.WriteStartElement("root"); 

foreach (var reader in readers) 
{ 
    reader.MoveToContent(); 
    reader.Read(); 
    while (!reader.EOF) 
    { 
        string elementName = reader.Name; 
        if (elementName.Equals("person", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        { 
            writer.WriteNode(reader, false); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            reader.Read(); 
        } 
    } 
} 

writer.WriteEndElement(); 
writer.WriteEndDocument(); 
... 
//dispose all readers and writers
```

It works ok and in final file I have **utf-8** in xml prolouge. But if I create readers like this:

```
var readers = files.Select(x => XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(x))).ToList();
```

I have the same **utf-8** in xml prolouge but there is corrupted data in final file. For instance, instead of symbol **å** I have �. I tried to find out the reason of this problem reading [Joel's article about encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) but there is no result. Why does it work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `XmlReader` like this:

```
XmlReader.Create("path/to/file.xml")
```

Then the encoding of the file will be inferred from the XML declaration, so `iso-8859-1`.  This is evidently correct.

When you create your `XmlReader` like this:

```
XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader("path/to/file.xml"))
```

You are using the overload that takes a `TextReader`.  A `TextReader` returns unicode, so there is no decoding to be done by `XmlReader`. The result is that the encoding specified in the declaration is entirely ignored.  This is mentioned in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z042k543(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A text reader returns a stream of Unicode characters, so the encoding specified in the XML declaration is not used by the XML reader to decode the data stream.

If you want to do it this way, you need to specify the correct encoding for the `StreamReader`, as it is not detecting this correctly:

```
new StreamReader("path/to/file.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: AFAIK unicode is a character set and utf-8/iso-8859-1 are are codings. Is unicode is used in both cases? Does wrong encoding mean that I recieve wrong numbers from binary data and finally this numbers is interpreted wrong using unicode character set?

Comment: @mtkachenko Your file (which is a load of bytes) is decoded to a string (unicode characters) and then re-encoded when you write it to a file again. The decoding is what's going wrong here, you are getting the wrong characters because your `StreamReader` is using the wrong decoder (it will default to UTF-8 as there's no BOM indicating otherwise).

Comment: Process: bytes -> to numbers based on encoding -> to string based on charater set. So the 2nd step is wrong and finally the 3rd too, right? Wrong way here: bytes->utf-8->unicode. Good way: bytes->iso-8859-1->unicode (or subset of unicode). Is it correct?

Comment: @mtkachenko There's no middle step, you're just going from bytes -> string and back again. All encodings are to/from unicode, as that's what all strings in .NET are.

Comment: Yes, but different encodings can use defferent numbers of bytes for one symbol (number).

Comment: @mtkachenko There are still only two steps, the 'numbers' in your second step are unicode character references.